# Coincidence Score in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently working on a project that consists of making a browser for a DB with Azure Cognitive Search. The browser should search for any similar coincidences in the corresponding fields and return a coincidence score for each returned result.
For example, imagine there is a `Surname` value on the DB and we wanted to search for all people whose surname is "Gomez". The idea would be that if the value is misspelled, e.g. "gmz", the browser should return all the values with a similar `Surname` field with a coincidence score indicating how similar the terms are, which in this case could be the number of equal letters in order: gmz/Gomez = 0.6
I've been searching for a while but the only thing I have found information about are Scoring profiles which seem to be a different thing. Does anyone know if this is possible or where I can find this info?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gomez and gmz are not coincidences at all. But if say, Gomez/Gomes, that 's a different story.

I would say you should use speller check and provide the score as your 'coincidence score':

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/speller-how-to-add